# reading a file stored in a variable Ksh Unix

Tags: ksh, variable

I'm having a hard time reading a file stored in a variable. it should be straightforward but somehow I'm missing something, can't find out what?

```
count=0 
mip="$(<fila.txt)"
while read -r line
do
  count=`expr $count + 1`
  echo "line $count "   
done < $mip
```

it's a really basic and simple script which count the number of lines like so, but when I used a variable **done < $mip** instead of the file name **done < fila.txt**. the script just outputs the file content like **cat fila.txt** instead of counting the lines.

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

any ideas ??

Comment: Don't read the contents of the file into a variable, just iterate over the file: `done < fila.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`done <$mip` still assumes that `$mip` is a filename.  It's not.

What you want is probably something like

```
printf '%s\n' "$mip" |
while IFS= read -r line; do
   printf 'line %d\n' "$(( ++count ))"
done
```

The more straight forward solution is

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
   printf 'line %d\n' "$(( ++count ))"
done <filea.txt
```

or even

```
cat -n filea.txt | sed 's/^ *\([0-9]*\).*$/line \1/'
```

That last command will use `cat` for enumerating the lines in the file and `sed` to delete the actual file contents.

Or, with `awk`, which is even more straightforward:

```
awk '{ printf("line %d\n", NR) }' filea.txt
```

Or, if you count the lines in the file first:

```
count=$( sed -n '$=' filea.txt )    # or:  count=$( wc -l <filea.txt )
printf 'line %d\n' {1..$count}
```

Comment: or `while … done <<<"$mip"`, if it's a non-ancient ksh.

Comment: Since you are using a pipe, all changes made to the `count` variable are done **in a subshell**, so the variable will only be useful in the loop

Comment: thanks it worked, and also for all  the details it's really helpful to learn from the best, again thank you